# How to install Homebrew on Mac OSX Snow Leopard?

Tags: curl, proxy, homebrew

I tried to install it a lot of times. I got this error:
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

It's probably because I am connected through a proxy server. 
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are alternative installations available at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation

The most relavent to you seems to be the 'untar anywhere' instructions.

1. Download https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master
2. `cd /usr/local`
3. Untar it with `tar -xz --strip 1 -f FILENAME`